# Form input to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to teach myself basic JavaScript and stuck for days with this simple concept.

I want to save a form input to a variable and later on execute a function,alert or whatever with that var.

```js
function myFunc() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  alert("Hello, " + userName + "!");
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="myFunc" ;>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is actually an example from a book but it does not work in jsfiddle and nor does it on my own server. I can call up the function from the console but it won't execute from the submit button.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `()` into `onSubmit` attribute.

**PS:** Also you add `;` into `<form>` tag (invalid) and you forgot both input closure `<input>` -> `<input/>`

```js
function myFunc() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  alert("Hello, " + userName + "!");
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="myFunc()">
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are learing JS, better read a little bit about, you can write code in a better way by following a design pattern (you can learn more [here](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

My solution will be

```js
(function () {
  // variables
  
  // cached elements
  var form = document.querySelector('#form'),
      nameInput = document.querySelector('#name'); 
  
  // event bindings
  form.addEventListener('submit', myFunc);
  
  // methods
  function myFunc (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the page reload
    
    alert(nameInput.value);
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
 <form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two brackets in your `onsubmit` expression. When you want to prevent the page from refreshing you could even `return false` inside your function.

```js
function myFunc() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  alert("Hello, " + userName + "!");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunc()">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Another way is to add a listener to your form, so you could get rid of `onsubmit` in general.

```js
function myFunc( event ) {
  var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  alert("Hello, " + userName + "!");
  event.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementsByTagName( 'form' )[ 0 ].addEventListener( 'submit', myFunc );
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But with this solution you need to use `preventDefault` on the event parameter.